# How to read local file that in located in the same directory as html using javascript

Tags: javascript, file, local, compression

I have an application that creates html files that containes a lot of data to draw. This files are alwayes  browsed  from local file system (no http protocol at all).

I have an idea to compress the data and than place it in a raw format in a separate .dat file that will be put in the same place as .html one.

It is not a problem to read and uncompress this .dat file when it is on a web server. But I don't now how to read it when both files .html and .dat are local.

Of course one can use browser file objects for it but in this case user will be alwayes asked to do a stupid action like to chose the the only file from an  control.

Comment: Where is the javascript running from? Did you get it from the server, or are your running from a local directory?

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't now how to read it when both files .html and .dat are local.

I take it you mean from JavaScript within that HTML file. Depending on the browser, you can't except via the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) (which, as you've observed, requires that you have the user select the file in an `input[type=file]` element).

The way you'd *want* to do this would be via ajax (`XMLHttpRequest`), and that would work in *some* browsers, but not in others. Chrome, for instance, denies all attempts to use ajax with `file://` URLs (e.g., in pages served from the file system), even from local pages, even when you're using a relative URL like `thefile.dat`. IE allows it (or at least, older versions of IE did; I haven't tried it lately).

So unfortunately, I think the only way you can do this is via the File API, with the attendant `input[type=file]`.